# Ajax+PHP to implement cascading select

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have a demo.html page, which contains two selections, the first one is "Type", and the second one is "Config", when I choose a certain type in the first selection, I want to use ajax to update the values in the second selection.
For example, Type may have values: VM, Server, DCA
and VM only has config "singe node", but DCA has Config "d0"-"d48". so if I select DCA in the first selection, I should have 49 options in the second one.

I searched online and did find some solutions, then I wrote some code by myself. The problem now is that whatever I select in the first selection, the second one will not be updated, it always return null.

Not sure where the prob is, the code looks fine :( Thanks for any help.

demo page

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Reservation System</title>

      <link href="jquery/ui/css/sunny/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <link href="jquery/datatables/css/mrbs-page.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="jquery/datatables/css/mrbs-table.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="jquery/datatables/css/ColReorder.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="jquery/datatables/css/ColVis.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mrbs.css.php" type="text/css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" media="print" href="css/mrbs-print.css.php" type="text/css">
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex">

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/ui/jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/ui/jquery-ui-i18n.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/ui/jquery-ui-datepicker-en.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/ui/jquery-ui-datepicker-en-US.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/datatables/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/datatables/js/ColReorder.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
       var xmlhttp;
       var url;
       function createXMLHttpRequest() {
          if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
             xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
          else
             xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
       }

       function showConfig(str) {
          url = "getOptions.php?type="+str;
          createXMLHttpRequest();
          xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
          xmlhttp.send(null);

          xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {handleStateChange()};
        }

       function handleStateChange() {
          if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
          {
                var str = xmlhttp.responseText;
                alert (url);
                createConfig(str);
           }
        }

       function createConfig(str) {
          var configs = str;
          var config = configs.split(",");
          while (document.getElementById("config").options.lengt>0)
                 document.getElementById("config").options.remove(0);
          for (var i=0; i<config.length; i++)
          {
                var ooption = document.createElement("option");
                ooption.value = config[i];
                ooption.text = config[i];
                document.getElementById("config").add(ooption);
           }
        }
</script>

<form id="add_room" class="form_admin" action="add.php" method="post">
      <fieldset>
      <legend>Add DCA</legend>
        <input type="hidden" name="type" value="room">
        <input type="hidden" name="area" value="2">

        <div>
          <label for="room_name">Name:</label>
          <input type="text" id="room_name" name="name" maxlength="50">
        </div>

        <div>
          <label for="room_description">Description:</label>
          <input type="text" id="room_description" name="description" maxlength="100">
        </div>

        <div>
          <label for="room_type">Type:</label>
          <select class="room_area_select" id="type_select" name="area" onchange="showConfig(this.value)"><option  value="VM">VM</option><option  value="Server">Server</option><option  value="DCA-V1">DCA-V1</option><option  value="DCA-V2">DCA-V2</option></select>
        </div>    

       <div>
        <label for = "config">config:</label>
        <select id="config" ></select>
       </div>

      </fieldset>
    </form>
```

getOptions.php file

```
<?php
$type = $_GET['type'];
echo $type;
$result = "";
if ($type == "DCA-V1") {
       for ($i=0;$i<47;$++)
          $result .= $i.",";
       $result .= "48";
}

else if ($type == "Server")
       $result .= "single node";

else if ($type == "VM") {
       $result .= "single host";
}
echo $result;
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are already using jQuery in your page, I suggest jQuery's ajax option.

Following should work. Update it accordingly.

**getOptions.php**

```
<?php
    $type = $_GET['type'];
    $result = "";
    if ($type == "DCA-V1") {
        for ($i=0;$i<47;$i++)
            $result .= $i.",";
        $result .= "48";
    } else if ($type == "Server") {
        $result .= "single node";
    } else if ($type == "VM") {
        $result .= "single host";
    }
    echo $result;
?>
```

**Demo Page**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#type_select').change(function() {

                    //Get current item's value
                    var type = $(this).val();

                    $.ajax({
                        url : "getOptions.php?type=" + type,
                        success : function(data) {
                            var result, opts = "";

                            //We get comma separated data
                            result = data.split(',');
                            //Prepare options
                            for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                                opts += "<option value='" + result[i] + "'>" + result[i] + "</option>";
                            }
                            //Populate second select
                            $('#config').html(opts);
                        },
                        error : function() {
                            alert("Error");
                        }
                    });
                });

                //By default populate options for currently selected item
                $('#type_select').trigger('change');
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="add_room" class="form_admin" action="add.php" method="post">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Add DCA</legend>
                <input type="hidden" name="type" value="room">
                <input type="hidden" name="area" value="2">

                <div>
                    <label for="room_name">Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="room_name" name="name" maxlength="50">
                </div>

                <div>
                    <label for="room_description">Description:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="room_description" name="description" maxlength="100">
                </div>

                <div>
                    <label for="room_type">Type:</label>
                    <select class="room_area_select" id="type_select" name="area">
                        <option  value="VM">VM</option>
                        <option  value="Server">Server</option>
                        <option  value="DCA-V1">DCA-V1</option>
                        <option  value="DCA-V2">DCA-V2</option>
                    </select>
                </div>    

                <div>
                    <label for = "config">config:</label>
                    <select id="config" ></select>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Tried providing some comments.

Let us know if you need any help.

Comment: Hi Vanga, I copied the code, and it stopped working at the first line: $(document).ready(function(), any idea what's wrong with it?

Comment: Don't just copy and paste code. Just use the code between script. Also Stackoverflow doesn't provide complete code. It will help you to get an idea of how to solve your problems. I changed the jQuery library in the first script tag as per my settings. That's why it is giving error.

Comment: Thanks Vanga, it works fine now. I missed "i" in "for ($i=0;$i<47;$i++)", I think it's the reason why I cannot get the select updated. But your code works pretty well, seems JQuery is a better choice.